# sorting js objects

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object which looks like this:

```
[
Object {url="123456", name="john", count="0", url="name/sine"},
Object {url="1668", name="ben", count="0", url="name/dcdc"},
Object {url="98465", name="mike", count="0", url="name/ssd"},
]
```

I need to sort the object by name but can't figure it out.

I found the following snippet which sort object with 2 parts:

```
namesObject.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.value > b.value){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(a.value < b.value){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

But how could I expand this to an object with four parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily like so...

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); });
```

Comment: That was easy. Thank you! I didn't know about localeCompare... just the ticket!